# Why does type(of:) return Metatype, rather than T.Type?

Tags: swift, types

I noticed that [`type(of:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/2885064-type) has this unexpected signature:

```
func type<T, Metatype>(of value: T) -> Metatype
```

whereas I would have expected:

```
func type<T>(of value: T) -> T.Type
```

The actual signature somehow takes 2 independent and unbounded type parameters, uses one of them as the parameter type, and the other as the return type. This seems to suggest that I can do something silly like this:

```
let foo: String = type(of: 1) // T is Int, Metatype is String
```

But when I actually tried it,

> Cannot convert value of type 'Int.Type' to specified type 'String'

So I don't get to specify `Metatype` after all, even though it's a generic type parameter. I was curious how the compiler did this, so I went to the [source code](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/2335eb87f8840aea231f12c3f21a33519354bb13/stdlib/public/core/Builtin.swift#L880) and checked. *I think* what's preventing me from doing that silly thing is this `@_semantics` annotation:

```
@_transparent
@_semantics("typechecker.type(of:)")
public func type<T, Metatype>(of value: T) -> Metatype {
```

I also saw some comments explaining that the implementation written here isn't actually called, and that this is directly handled by the type checker itself. But that doesn't answer my question - **why does `type(of:)` return a completely unrelated type parameter `Metatype`, rather than `T.Type`?**

My guess is that there is some edge case where `type(of:)` will return a completely unrelated type to `T`, but I have no idea what that is.

Comment: Huh, I didn't even know this was a function in the standard library, I thought it was a special form in the language.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**tl;dr:** The behavior of `type(of:)` depends on whether `T` is existential or concrete, and the type system can't effectively reflect the actual return type syntactically, so it's handled directly in the type checking system. `Metatype` is specifically not bound in code to be the same as `T` so that the effective behavior can be specialized. `Metatype` and `T` are not necessarily related.

---

`type(of:)` is special in that its behavior differs depending on the type passed into it. Specifically, it has special behavior for existential types by being able to reach *through* the existential box to get the underlying type of the value passed in. For example:

```
func myType<T>(of value: T) -> T.Type {
    return T.self
}

protocol Foo {}
struct X: Foo {}

let x = X()
print(type(of: x), "vs.", myType(of: x)) // => X vs. X

let f: Foo = X()
print(type(of: f), "vs.", myType(of: f)) // => X vs. Foo
```

When given an existential type like `Foo`, a return type of `T.Type` could *only* return the metatype of the existential itself (i.e. `Foo.self`), as opposed to the metatype of the *value* inside of the existential container (`X.self`). So instead of returning `T.Type`, `type(of:)` returns an *unrelated* type `Metadata` which is bound to the correct type in the type checker itself. This is the edge case you were looking for:

> My guess is that there is some edge case where `type(of:)` will return a completely unrelated type to `T`, but I have no idea what that is.

If you look in [`lib/Sema/TypeChecker.h`](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/a5a79f23c0257c36c297d3c1b9275a873434468a/lib/Sema/TypeChecker.h), you can see some special semantics declarations for several stdlib function types:

```
/// Special-case type checking semantics for certain declarations.
enum class DeclTypeCheckingSemantics {
  /// A normal declaration.
  Normal,

  /// The type(of:) declaration, which performs a "dynamic type" operation,
  /// with different behavior for existential and non-existential arguments.
  TypeOf,

  /// The withoutActuallyEscaping(_:do:) declaration, which makes a nonescaping
  /// closure temporarily escapable.
  WithoutActuallyEscaping,

  /// The _openExistential(_:do:) declaration, which extracts the value inside
  /// an existential and passes it as a value of its own dynamic type.
  OpenExistential,
};
```

The key one here is `TypeOf`, which is indeed returned for functions with the `@_semantics("typechecker.type(of:)")` attribute you noted. (You can see how that attribute is checked in [`TypeChecker::getDeclTypeCheckingSemantics`](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/a5a79f23c0257c36c297d3c1b9275a873434468a/lib/Sema/TypeChecker.cpp#L505))

If you go looking for usages of `TypeOf`, there are two key locations in type-checking:

1. [`getTypeOfReferenceWithSpecialTypeCheckingSemantics`](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/583d617254af7067f36e87cc276373232af73ca1/lib/Sema/ConstraintSystem.cpp#L2028) which injects the type constraint in the type checker constraint system. **`type(of:)` is handled here as an *overload*, because `Metadata` isn't actually bound; the constraint solver here applies an effective type checking constraint which constrains `Metadata` to be the actual type of `value`.** The key here is that `type(of:)` is written in this way so that it *would be* an overload, and handled here.
2. [`ExprRewriter::finishApply`](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/fd8e34913a68d4d5dfed6213aa5efbcd27dafbf8/lib/Sema/CSApply.cpp#L7515) which performs the actual expression rewriting in the AST to replace the return type with the effective actual type of the value

From (1):

```
// Proceed with a "DynamicType" operation. This produces an existential
// metatype from existentials, or a concrete metatype from non-
// existentials (as seen from the current abstraction level), which can't
// be expressed in the type system currently.
```

Pulling back some history — this was implemented back in commit [1889fde2284916e2c368c9c7cc87906adae9155b](https://github.com/apple/swift/commit/1889fde2284916e2c368c9c7cc87906adae9155b). The commit message from Joe is illuminating:

> Resolve `type(of:)` by overload resolution rather than parse hackery.
>
> `type(of:)` has behavior whose type isn't directly representable in Swift's type system, since it produces both concrete and existential metatypes. In Swift 3 we put in a parser hack to turn `type(of: <expr>)` into a DynamicTypeExpr, but this effectively made `type(of:)` a reserved name. It's a bit more principled to put `Swift.type(of:)` on the same level as other declarations, even with its special-case type system behavior, and we can do this by special-casing the type system we produce during overload resolution if `Swift.type(of:)` shows up in an overload set. This also lays groundwork for handling other declarations we want to ostensibly behave like normal declarations but with otherwise inexpressible types, viz. `withoutActuallyEscaping` from SE-0110.

Since then, as we can see from `WithoutActuallyEscaping` and `OpenExistential`, other special functions have been rewritten to take advantage of this.

Comment: If I understand correctly, if `type(of:)` were to return `T.Type` instead, it would only be able to return concrete metatypes, right? It's interesting how Swift has not one, not two, but three of these special cases :-)

Comment: @Sweeper I've gone ahead and clarified the answer a bit to make this more explicit: if `type(of:)` were to return `T.Type`, passing in an existential type like `protocol Foo` could only return to you the type of the _protocol_ itself, rather than the type of the value, which isn't terribly useful.