# How Swift implement type(of:)?

Tags: swift, metadata, typeof, dynamictype

As we all know, Objective-C class owns an `isa` pointer, so we can get class metadata by this pointer, and Swift value type DO NOT have an `isa`, but `type(of: aInstance)` still return its metatype, how does it works?

```
struct Foo {
    var bar: Int
}

var foo: Any = Foo(bar: 10)
print(type(of: foo))
let ptr = withUnsafeMutablePointer(to: &foo) {
    UnsafeMutableRawPointer($0)
}
print(ptr)
print(ptr.assumingMemoryBound(to: Int.self).pointee)

// Foo
// 0x00000001000081d8
// 10
```

The memory address owns the value `10`, and how can Swift infer its dynamic type by `type(of:)` at runtime?

Comment: Do you realise that unlike classes, structs are not polymorphic? If it is a struct, the type can be completely worked out at compile time.

Comment: Anyway, the code that implements "finding dynamic types" is [here](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/main/stdlib/public/runtime/Casting.cpp#L547).

Comment: While not a direct answer to your question, also worth checking out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67051520/why-does-typeof-return-metatype-rather-than-t-type/67051785 (asked by @Sweeper). Much of the work that `type(of:)` does can be simplified at compile-time, but for true runtime checks, there is an entire Swift runtime library (like Objective-C's runtime library) which handles similar behavior. The runtime library has access to the info of `Metatype` at runtime.