# Understanding “Finding the Dynamic Type in a Generic Context”

Tags: swift, generics, types, protocols, type-systems

I would like to understand this section.

I'm reading [Finding the Dynamic Type in a Generic Context](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/type(of:)#Finding-the-Dynamic-Type-in-a-Generic-Context) that has this snippet:

```swift
func printGenericInfo<T>(_ value: T) {
    let t = type(of: value)
    print("'\(value)' of type '\(t)'")
}

protocol P {}
extension String: P {}

let stringAsP: P = "Hello!"
printGenericInfo(stringAsP)
// 'Hello!' of type 'P'
```

... that's followed up by this sentence:

> This unexpected result occurs because the call to `type(of: value)` inside `printGenericInfo(_:)` must return a metatype that is an instance of `T.Type` , ***but `String.self` (the expected dynamic type) is not an instance of `P.Type` (the concrete metatype of value).***

1. Why is `String.self` not an instance of `P.Type` when I can run this code?

```swift
func f(_ t: P.Type) { print("...") }

f(String.self)
```

2. Why does `type(of:)` return the concrete metatype outside but not inside generic functions?

```swift
print("'\(stringAsP)' of type '\(type(of: stringAsP))'")
// 'Hello!' of type 'String'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a protocol `P`, there are two kinds of metatypes that you can write with `P`. You can write `(any P).Type` (aka `P.Protocol`), which is the metatype of `P` itself, and `any P.Type` (aka `P.Type`), which is an existential type representing "the metatype of some type that conforms to `P`".

`String.self` is an instance of `any P.Type`, but not `(any P).Type`. The documentation is incorrect here. It probably meant to say `(any P).Type`. Otherwise this whole thing doesn't make sense.

`type(of:)` has two different behaviours depending on what kind of type its type parameter `T` is. Your `printGenericInfo` also has a type parameter `T`, so to avoid confusion, I will call them `typeof.T` and `printGenericInfo.T` respectively.

If `typeof.T` is a non-existential type, then it returns the metatype of `typeof.T`. If `typeof.T` is an existential (i.e. protocol) type `any E`, it would return an `any E.Type`, *not* `(any E).Type`. After all, the former is much more useful - it can tell you the actual type that the existential type "wraps". `type(of:)` in this case needs to "unwrap" the existential and "look inside" of it.

```
let s1 = ""
let s2: Any = s1
// typeof.T is String
type(of: s1)

// typeof.T is Any, an existential type, so type(of:) unwraps it and returns String.self
// this would be pretty useless if it just returned Any.self
type(of: s2)
```

**This difference in behaviour is exactly what your `printGenericInfo` *lacks*.** In fact, this kind of semantics cannot be written in Swift's syntax. This is why `type(of:)` [has the weird signature](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67051520/5133585) it has - it returns a `Metatype` type parameter, seemingly unrelated to the type it takes in.

`type(of:)` uses special annotations to allow the compiler to type-check `type(of:)` calls in a special way. Depending on `typeof.T`, `Metatype` could either be `typeof.T.Type` (when `typeof.T` is not existential) or `any typeof.T.Type` (when `typeof.T` is existential). Note that this is a *compile time* check. The type parameters of generic functions are decided at compile time, not at runtime.

`printGenericInfo` doesn't unwrap `printGenericInfo.T` and look inside of it. It just directly passes that to `type(of:)`, so `typeof.T` is decided to be `printGenericInfo.T`, a type parameter, which is not an existential type.

When you call `printGenericInfo(stringAsP)`, `printGenericInfo.T` is decided to be `any P` - an existential type. This doesn't change `typeof.T`, which is still `printGenericInfo.T`, a non-existential type. So at runtime, `type(of:)` returns the metatype of `any P`, and that is `(any P).Type`.

If you do `let t = type(of: value as Any)` instead, then `type(of:)` will see that `typeof.T` is an existential type (`Any`), and so it will unwrap the existential type and look inside of it.

Comment: Thank you so much. If you have time, please take a look a my other question here: ([source](https://forums.swift.org/t/what-is-the-name-of-this-technique-pattern/70053))

Answer (score -1):

The reason is that you instantiate a `String` by using `let = "this is a string"`.

You do not (and cannot) instantiate a `P`. `P` is a protocol and other types can only *conform* to it. But in the end, when creating a value for a variable, you have to explicitly instantiate a type. And that type might conform to a protocol, or not. Conformance is something else than identity.

Edit, more clarification on your questions:

1. `String.self` is not an instance of `P`.
   That is because when writing `extension String: P {}`, you tell it that any *instance* of `String` can be seen as a `P`. That means the type itself `String.self`, does not conform to `P`. (Back to the point: conformance is not identity.)
2. In this line `let stringAsP: P = "Hello!"` you tell the compiler to explicitly forget that the value is a `String`. That then causes the compiler to generate this method `printGenericInfo` with `P` as a type. You then can think of `type(of:)` then saying "well, in the method definition you're saying you pass in a `P`, so I will just repeat that back to you. No need to do hard work to look things up manually.". If you then follow Apple's example of first casting it to `Any`, `type(of:)` will actually do some work and look up the explicit type.

Comment: sorry, at the first question, I mean `P.Type`, not `P`

Comment: @ThaiD.V. I updated my answer to go more into details for you.

Comment: I still don't get it.
1. `P` and `P.Type` are not the same thing
2. Swift Generics model is not monomorphization, so I don't understand what you mean by "explicitly forget"